# Magento 2 "No Payment Methods" in Admin New Order

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, payment-methods

In a **Magento 2.3.1** site, I have **two third-party payment methods** and **PayPal Express Checkout** enabled. On the frontend, the three works perfectly. But, when I am trying to create a new order on admin panel, the payment methods are not displayed when I click on **Get shipping methods and rates**

[image]

I tested enabled the method **Check / Money Order** in my developer environment, and this is displayed correctly:

[image]

What could be causing the other three not are displayed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your third-party payment methods don't support admin order. Same for **PayPal Express Checkout**. **PayPal Express Checkout** redirects to Paypal that's why this is not working for admin section if you enabled by hacking code.

For **Check / Money Order** this payment method extends **Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod** class. If you open then you can see following code snippet:

```
/**
 * Payment Method feature
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_canUseInternal = true;
```

That's why this is work for admin.

For express checkout this is disabled.

> vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Express.php

```
/**
 * Availability option
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_canUseInternal = false;
```

Comment: You are correct; the problem is third-party payment methods have the **protected $_canUseInternal = false;** I will review with them what options there are. Thanks.

Comment: Have you find any option to allow Paypal in admin?