# Magento 2: Payment methods not showing on admin create order

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, sales-order, payment-methods

When creating an order from the admin panel I cannot see payment methods available
However, in the fronted, customers can see the available payment methods, which are  CHECK / MONEY ORDER and CyberSource ( CREDIT CARD  )

There are no errors in the console neither in the logs.

Any suggestions on how to debug this?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With reference to [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281246/magento-2-no-payment-methods-in-admin-new-order) answer

For **Check / Money Order** this payment method extends `Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod` class. If you open then you can see following code snippet:

> protected $_canUseInternal = false;

This is the reason it is not working on admin side.

So, please check **Paypal** as reference so you will have better idea.

Happy Coding. :)

Comment: thanks man you saved me upvoted

Comment: @AsadUllah happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Try choosing a "Shipping Method" first, then the Payment method options will show.

Comment: Thanks! But is this a core bug?

Comment: Sure seems that way.  When you have a decline, the card is gone, and you have to click the shipping method again.  Or update the order.